# Python - Vk_api.bot_longpoll (messages.getChat)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Как сделать так, чтобы бот возвращал мне название беседы, из которой пришла соответствующая команда

```
def send_message(text):
    vk.messages.send(
    random_id = random_id,
    chat_id = chat_id,
    message = text)

import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import random
import datetime
import time

token = 'Мой токен'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

while True:
    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 187502244)
    try:

        for event in longpoll.listen():

            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat and event.object.text:

                clock = datetime.datetime.today()
                random_id = random.randint(1, 2147483647)
                chat_id = event.chat_id
                message_text = event.object.text.lower()

                members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id, fields='count')['count']
                title = vk.messages.getChat(chat_id=event.chat_id)['title'] #Строка, в которой я пытаюсь получить название беседы
                print(title)

                if message_text.startswith('/'):
                    if message_text == "/timenow":
                        send_message("Сейчас в городе - " + str(clock.hour) + ":" + str(clock.minute) + " &#128339;")

                    elif message_text == "/info":

                        send_message("Участников в беседе: " + str(members) + " &#128104;\n")

                    elif message_text == "/help":
                        send_message(
                            "/info - Информация о беседе &#128200;\n"
                            "/timenow - Который час &#128339;")

                    else:
                        send_message(
                            "&#10060; Нераспознанная команда! &#10060;\nЧтобы вызвать список команд отправьте '/help'")

    except Exception as E:
        print(Exception)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю актуально али нет но.
Это

```
title = vk.messages.getChat(chat_id=event.chat_id)['title'] #Строка, в которой я пытаюсь получить название беседы
                print(title)
```

Заменяете на это

```
request=vk.messages.getConversationsById(peer_ids=event.chat_id)
for response in request['items']:
    chat_settings= response['chat_settings']
    title= chat_settings['title']
    print(title)
```

И getChat только для логина через пользователя насколько я понял а это пофиксили давно